# Ruby on Rails - SQL Query count

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I need to count all the microposts of my image where the status is equal to **new**.

```
<% for column in @images %>
  <%= column.id %>
  <%= column.microposts.count() %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried this line but it doesn't work:

```
<%= column.microposts.count(" WHERE status='new' ") %>
```

Is there a way I can add a condition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
column.microposts.where(:status => 'new').count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
column.microposts.find_all_by_status('new').count
```